# Ajax beforeSend sometimes doesn't fire to show bootstrap progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have 3 Bootstrap tabs, each with a table showing query results.  When the search button is clicked, or a tab is changed, an ajax call is triggered that has a `beforeSend` function which shows a Bootstrap progress bar.  The progress bar always shows the first time I load the page, but then is only intermittent after that.  I can't seem to figure out when it shows and when it doesn't.  The searches can take 5 or 6 seconds, so it's really necessary to have something for the user to know the search is running.

I saw some threads about async:false causing issues in chrome, but I don't have that set and the issue also shows up in Firefox.

I also saw a thread about having the ajax call wrapped in a document.ready, but this code is in a separate .js file?

OK, the function is long.  I'm putting the whole thing in case there's some conflict.  I tried commenting out the multiple ajax calls in the success function and just running the one with the beforeSend function but the issue still showed up.

Let me know if you have any ideas to troubleshoot or a potential work around...Thank you!

```
function submitSearch(method) {
  $("#programCount").html('');
  $("#plotCount").html('');
  $("#treeCount").html('');
  checkdata=validate_input();
  if (checkdata===false) {
     return;
  }
  yearLower= $('#startYr').val();
  yearUpper= $('#endYr').val();
   
  var state=[];
  if(!($('.state_sub_checkbox:checkbox:checked').length === $('.state_sub_checkbox').length)){
      $('.state_sub_checkbox:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
                state.push(this.value);
            });
    }
  var TSN=[];
  var treeSpecies=[];
  if (!($('.species_sub_checkbox:checkbox:checked').length===$('.species_sub_checkbox').length)) {
      $('.species_sub_checkbox:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
 //         species.push(this.value);
          TSN.push(this.value);
          treeSpecies.push($(this).closest("label").text().trim());
      });
  }

  var progList=[];
  var progListNames=[];
  if (!($('.program_sub_checkbox:checkbox:checked').length ===$('.program_sub_checkbox').length)) {
      $('.program_sub_checkbox:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
                progList.push(this.value);
                progListNames.push($(this).closest("label").text().trim());
            }); 
    }    
    
  forestHealth =[];
  if (!($('.FHI_checkbox:checkbox:checked').length===$('.FHI_checkbox').length)) {
      $('.FHI_checkbox:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
          forestHealth.push(this.value);
      });
  }
  crown="";
  if (!($('.crown_checkbox:checkbox:checked').length===$('.crown_checkbox').length)) {
      crown=$('input[name="crown"]:checked').val();
  }
  height=[];
  if (!($('.height_checkbox:checkbox:checked').length===$('.height_checkbox').length)) {
      $('.height_checkbox:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
          height.push(this.value);
      });
  }
  
  tree_status=[];
  if (!($('.tree_status:checkbox:checked').length===$('.tree_status').length)) {
      $('.tree_status:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
          tree_status.push(this.value);
      });      
  }
  
  missingDBH = $('#DBH_missing').prop('checked');
  dbhUpper = $('#endDBH').val();
  dbhLower = $('#startDBH').val();
  missingHeight = $('#height_missing').prop('checked');
  heightUpper = $('#endHeight').val();
  heightLower = $('#startHeight').val();

  var limit=10;  
  var offset="";
  if (method==='ajax_getPrograms') {
      fields = ['pkProgramID','fldName','fldOrganization','fldProgramStartDate','fldProgramEndDate','fldStates'];
      limit=$('#num_results').val();
      offset=$('#program_table_offset').val();
    }
  if (method==='ajax_getPlots') {
      fields = ['programID','lat','long','plotSampleYear','_nefin_plotID', '_nefin_plot_obsID'];  
      limit=$('#num_results_plot').val();
      offset=$('#plot_table_offset').val();      
  }  
  if (method==='ajax_getTrees') {
      fields = ['programID','TSN','treeSpecies','DBH','treeStatus','treeSampleYear','_nefin_plotID','_nefin_plot_obsID','_nefin_treeID','_nefin_tree_obsID'];   
      limit=$('#num_results_tree').val();
      offset=$('#tree_table_offset').val();      
  }
  
  var posturl = baseURL + "data/"+method;
  var formData = new FormData();
  if (progList.length>0) {
      formData.append('progList',progList);
      formData.append('progListNames',progListNames);
  }
  if (TSN.length>0) {
      formData.append('TSN', TSN);
      formData.append('treeSpecies', treeSpecies);
  }

  
  if (yearLower!==filters.year_min) {
      formData.append('yearLower', yearLower);

  }
  if (yearUpper!==filters.year_max) {
      formData.append('yearUpper', yearUpper);
  }
  if(!($('.state_sub_checkbox:checkbox:checked').length === $('.state_sub_checkbox').length)){
      formData.append('state', state);
  }
  if (forestHealth.length>0) {
      formData.append('forestHealth',forestHealth);
  }
  if (crown!=="") {
      formData.append('crown',crown);
  }
  if (tree_status.length>0) {
      formData.append('status',tree_status);
  }
  var height_change=false;
  if (heightUpper!==filters.height_max) {
      height_change=true;
      formData.append('heightUpper',heightUpper);
  }
  
  if (heightLower!==filters.height_min) {
      height_change=true;
      formData.append('heightLower',heightLower);
  }
  if (height_change===true || missingHeight===false) {
      formData.append('missingHeight',missingHeight);
  }
  var dbh_change=false;
  if (dbhUpper!==filters.dbh_max) {
      dbh_change=true;
      formData.append('dbhUpper',dbhUpper);
  }
  
  if (dbhLower!==filters.dbh_min) {
      dbh_change=true;
      formData.append('dbhLower',dbhLower);
  }
  if (dbh_change===true || missingDBH===false) {
      formData.append('missingDBH',missingDBH);
  }

   //get options in array for getData variable
  var getData = {};
formData.forEach(function(value, key){
        getData[key] = value;  
});

var getDataJSON = JSON.stringify(getData);

  formData.append('fields',fields);
  formData.append('limit',limit);
  formData.append('offset',offset);
  
updateSearchParamHTML(formData);
  $.ajax({
            url: posturl,
            cache: false,
            data: formData,
            method: 'POST',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            type: 'POST',
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('.progress').show();
                $('.progress-bar').attr('style', 'width: 100%;');

            },
            complete: function(){
                $('.progress').hide();
                $('.progress-bar').attr('style', 'width: 0%;');

            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                console.log(xhr);
                console.log(status);
                console.log(error);
            },
            success: function (data) {
                var data2 = JSON.parse(data);

                    $('#datasetErrors').removeClass('show');
                    $('#datasetErrors').addClass('hidden');
                    var datasetTable='';
                    
                    $('#getData').val(getDataJSON);

                    if (method==='ajax_getPrograms') {
                        
                        //assemble JSON of programs returned for data download
                        var programArray=[];
//                        console.log(data2);
                        if (data2.data && Object.keys(data2.data).length !== 0) {
                            $.each(data2.data, function (i, d) {
                                programArray.push(d['pkProgramID']);
                            });                       
                        }
                        //console.log(programArray);
                        var projectIDsJSON = JSON.stringify(programArray);
                        $('#projectIDs').val(projectIDsJSON);
                        
                        if (data2.resultCount<limit){
                            $("#program_next_btn").hide();
                        }
                        else {
                            $("#program_next_btn").show();                            
                        }
                        datasetTable = createProgramTable(data2.data);
                        $("#programCount").html('<strong>Your search returned '+data2.resultCount+' program(s) with tree data in our inventory.</strong>');
                        $("#programTable tbody").fadeOut(100, function () {
                            $(this).empty().html(datasetTable).fadeIn(); //Empty content and repopulate
                    });
                }
                if (method==='ajax_getPlots') {                      
                        //console.log(data2);
                        //console.log(programIDs);
                        var programIDs=data2.programIDs;
                        var projectIDsJSON = JSON.stringify(programIDs);
                        $('#projectIDs').val(projectIDsJSON);                        
                        if (data2.resultCount<=limit){
                            $("#plot_next_btn").hide();
                        }
                        else {
                            $("#plot_next_btn").show();                            
                        }
                        datasetTable = createPlotTable(data2.data, data2.fuzzflag);
                        //console.log(data2.fuzzflag);
                        $("#plotCount").html('<strong>Your search returned '+data2.resultCount+' plot observations in our inventory.</strong>');
                        $("#plotTable tbody").fadeOut(100, function () {
                            $(this).empty().html(datasetTable).fadeIn(); //Empty content and repopulate
                    });
                }
                if (method==='ajax_getTrees') {
                        //assemble JSON of programs returned for data download
                        //console.log(data2);
                        var projectIDsJSON = JSON.stringify(data2.programIDs);
                        $('#projectIDs').val(projectIDsJSON);
                       // console.log($('#projectIDs').val());
                        if (data2.resultCount<=limit){
                            $("#tree_next_btn").hide();
                        }
                        else {
                            $("#tree_next_btn").show();                            
                        }                    
                        datasetTable = createTreeTable(data2.data, data2.fuzzflag);
                        $("#treeCount").html('<strong>Your search returned '+data2.resultCount+' tree observations in our inventory.</strong>');
                        $("#treeTable tbody").fadeOut(100, function () {
                            $(this).empty().html(datasetTable).fadeIn(); //Empty content and repopulate
                    });
                }
                $("#download-tab-nav").prop("disabled",false);
                
                //check if we are on the download tab and update downloads if needed
                //console.log ("active tab: "+$('#tableTab .active').attr('id'));
                if ($('#tableTab .active').attr('id')=="download-tab-nav"){
                        var programID = $('#projectIDs').val();
                        var posturl = baseURL + "data/ajax_getProgramFiles";
                        var formData = new FormData();   
                        formData.append('programID',programID);
                      $.ajax({
                                url: posturl,
                                cache: false,
                                data: formData,
                                method: 'POST',
                                contentType: false,
                                processData: false,
                                type: 'POST',
                                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                                    console.log(xhr);
                                    console.log(status);
                                    console.log(error);
                                },
                                success: function (data) {
                                    var data2 = JSON.parse(data);
                                //    var data2=data;
                                //   console.log(data2);
                                   var file_download_div='';
                                   file_download_div = populateFileDownloadDiv(data2);             
                                   $("#fileDownloadDiv").html(file_download_div);
                                   setSelectedFiles();
                                    }
                                });    
                }
                //set hidden field to indicate if any of the programs returned are fuzzed
                var fuzzed=false;
                programArray = $('#projectIDs').val();
                var ajaxurl2 = baseURL + "data/ajax_arefuzzed";
                $.ajax({
                      method: "POST",
                      url: ajaxurl2,
                      data: {data : programArray}
                    })
                      .done(function(data) {
                          var data2 = JSON.parse(data);
                        $('#fuzzPlots').val(data2.fuzzed);
                      });

            }
        });
}
```

The HTML

```
<div class="table-responsive">
      <table id="plotTable" class="table table-striped table-centered" style="width:100%">
           <thead>
               <tr>
                 <th>Plot ID</th>
                 <th>Latitude</th>
                 <th>Longitude</th>
                 <th>Sample Year</th>
                 <th>Original Data</th>
               </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
               <tr>
                 <td class="text-center" colspan="5">
                   <div class="progress"> 
                     <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:0%">
                     </div> 
                   </div>                                            
                 </td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
      </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I believe, that instead of showing a 100% progress bar, you should show a Circular Loading animation. As the progress bars generally work great for those applications where the progress of the task is known. Loading animations work great where the time taken by a task is indefinite.

Comment: The .show() for the .progress div isn't happening, even if I put a different animation in there.  So I guess it doesn't matter that it's a bootstrap progress bar functionality wise. Is there a better way to trigger the display of the loading animation other than beforeSend maybe?

Comment: I've posted an answer. Do check try those methods and let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What was happening is that in the success code of the ajax call I was replacing the tbody of each table.  For example, in the plotTable:

```
$("#plotTable tbody").fadeOut(100, function () {
$(this).empty().html(datasetTable).fadeIn(); //Empty content and repopulate
  });
```

But the progress bar was in the tbody of the table. So then when I wanted to set the progress bar to be visible, it was no longer in the table.

Answer (score 1):

By seeing the code and description I understood that you are looking for some progressible tab content where data is coming on tab click and until it did not come progress bar should appear there.

You can add a progress bar in the tab and remove it once data is returned.
check the below code might be helpful to you.

```js
var progressBarHtml = '<div id="progressBar"><div id="myBar"></div></div>';
var progressBarspeed = 10;
var intervalId;
var i = 0;

function showProgress(currentTab) {
    if ($("#progressBar").length > 0) {
        $("#progressBar").remove();
        clearInterval(intervalId);
       i = 0;
    }
    $("#" + currentTab).append(progressBarHtml);
    function move() {
        if (i == 0) {
            i = 1;
            var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
            var width = 1;
            intervalId = setInterval(frame, progressBarspeed);

            function frame() {
                if (width >= 100) {
                    clearInterval(intervalId);
                    i = 0;
                    OnceProgressBarLoaded(currentTab);
                } else {
                    width++;
                    elem.style.width = width + "%";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    move();
}

function OnceProgressBarLoaded(currentTab) {

    console.log(currentTab + "Tab data Loaded");
    $("#progressBar").remove();
    //call your response here.
    var dataId = currentTab + 'Data';
    $("#" + dataId).show();
}

function openCity(evt, tabId) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(tabId).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
    $(".tabdata").hide();
    showProgress(tabId);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tabdata").hide();
})
```

```css
 body {font-family: Arial;}
         /* Style the tab */
         .tab {
         overflow: hidden;
         border: 1px solid #ccc;
         background-color: #f1f1f1;
         }
         /* Style the buttons inside the tab */
         .tab button {
         background-color: inherit;
         float: left;
         border: none;
         outline: none;
         cursor: pointer;
         padding: 14px 16px;
         transition: 0.3s;
         font-size: 17px;
         }
         /* Change background color of buttons on hover */
         .tab button:hover {
         background-color: #ddd;
         }
         /* Create an active/current tablink class */
         .tab button.active {
         background-color: #ccc;
         }
         /* Style the tab content */
         .tabcontent {
         display: none;
         padding: 6px 12px;
         border: 1px solid #ccc;
         border-top: none;
         }
         .tabdata {
         background: white;
         }
         #myProgress {
         width: 100%;
         background-color: #ddd;
         }
         #myBar {
         width: 1%;
         height: 30px;
         background-color: #04AA6D;
         }
```

```html
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <h2>Tabs With Loader</h2>
      <p>Click on the buttons inside the tabbed menu:</p>
      <div class="tab">
         <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
         <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
         <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
      </div>
      <div id="London" class="tabcontent">
         <div id="LondonData" class="tabcontent">
            <h3>London</h3>
            <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
         <div id="ParisData" class="tabdata">
            <h3>Paris</h3>
            <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
         <div id="TokyoData" class="tabdata">
            <h3>Tokyo</h3>
            <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
         </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I also have a search button where the tab stays the same but the search results are updated and need a progress bar.  I did figure out what was going wrong, but I did not end up having the relevant info in my question that would have made it possible to figure out. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to do this:

**1. Generalise the progress/loading animation for all ajax requests using the below code:**

//jQuery 1.9 onwards

// Ref: http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#ajax-events-should-be-attached-to-document

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
  $('.progress').show();
  $('.progress-bar').attr('style', 'width: 100%;');
});

$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
  $('.progress').hide();
  $('.progress-bar').attr('style', 'width: 0%;');
});
```

**2. Do it this way for your ajax code:**

```
updateSearchParamHTML(formData);
//Show loader before ajax call starts
$('.progress').show();
$('.progress-bar').attr('style', 'width: 100%;');
$.ajax({
    url: posturl,
    cache: false,
    data: formData,
    .
    .
    .
    //Hide loader in complete call
    complete: function(){
        $('.progress').hide();
        $('.progress-bar').attr('style', 'width: 0%;');
    },
```

I hope any of these will work for you.

Comment: Thank you so much! Neither of those worked because of what was happening- I did figure it out. I did not end up having the relevant info in my question that would have made it possible to figure out.  I'll post an answer.